# Codemirror Object has no method 'getAttribute'

Tags: jquery, typeerror, codemirror

***I'm using jQuery***

```
<textarea name="" id="upEditor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($('#upEditor'), {
    stylesheet:'monokai.css'
});
```

I dont know why it doesn't work, in the console, it said :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getAttribute'
```

please help -thanks

Comment: It seems that function accepts DOM element object instead of a jQuery object, try with `$('#upEditor').get(0)`.

Comment: It worked with no error but then the whole textarea just dissappear

Comment: The textarea disappears by design: CodeMirror sets its display to none and injects itself as a sibling. btw `$('#upEditor')[0]` instead of `$('#upEditor').get(0)` saves you a function call.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe caused by dom delay init. And also `[0]` should be added

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($('#upEditor')[0], {
    stylesheet:'monokai.css'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `$('#upEditor')[0]` to `document.getElementById('upEditor')`. This should fix your problem right away